# HTML/CSS: Keep my logo at equal distance from the top and bottom of my navbar

Tags: html, css

#### My Problem

I am trying to keep my logo at the left of my navbar and also keep it at equal distance from the top and bottom of the navbar. (explained in the provided picture)

#### HTML:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div id="logo-nav" class="col-4">
                <a href="/" title="Home">
                    <img class="logo-nav" src="images/logo-2.png" alt="My Logo">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

#### CSS:

```
.container {
    max-width :100%;
    margin: auto;
}

.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #181827;
}

.logo-nav{
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto ;
}

.row {
    width:100%;
    height: 160px;
}

.col-12 {
    width:100%;
}

.col-8 {
    width:66.6%;
}

.col-6 {
    width:50%
}

.col-4 {
    width:33.3%;
}
```

#### Explanation

The RED BOX is where my logo currently is, seems like it is stuck at the top of the navbar.

The GREEN BOX is where I want it to be - In the middle of the navbar: at equal distance from the bottom and from the top (NOT LEFT TO RIGHT, I want it to Stick to the LEFT as it is right now)

[image]

So I tried to research it online which led me to try the

```
.logo-nav{
    position: absolute;
    margin:auto ;
```

But unfortunately it did not give me the result I wanted. This is why I'm here

I think what I got wrong is the understanding of how the `position` and `margin` work.

So My Question is: **how do I get from the RED BOX to the GREEN BOX? (What did I get wrong in my code?)**

#### And most importantly

Thank you for your input :)

Comment: since you already set your nav to a fixed height (70px), could you just give .logo-nav enough padding-top to push down the image to the appropriate position?  (no absolute positioning) -- I assume you know the size of your image.

Comment: @andi it's not 100% nice variant: logo can have different height and in your case user must change padding every time he/she change size of logo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Centering an Image in a twitter bootstrap navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352791/centering-an-image-in-a-twitter-bootstrap-navbar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this variant:

```
.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #181827;
    position: relative;
}

.logo-nav{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: In my cases, I like `margin-top: -@logoHeight / 2;` instead of transform.

Comment: @MartinHomola in this variant we must have a fixed height for logo, am I right?

Comment: Yep, I often know height of logo. As I said, in my cases. :)

Comment: @0_jump try to add .navbar {position: relative} too

Comment: @0_jump yes, I've checked, my edited variant must work. Check please codepen - https://codepen.io/fox_hover/pen/ad63148c8ccbe2d7f15d21643d0f8a78

Answer (score 1):

You could apply some `flexbox` properties to `#logo-nav`

```css
.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #181827;
}

#logo-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#logo-nav a img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  /* ensure the image height does not exceed the container height */
  max-height: 70px;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 160px;
}

.col-12 {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-8 {
  width: 66.6%;
}

.col-6 {
  width: 50%
}

.col-4 {
  width: 33.3%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
      <div id="logo-nav" class="col-4">
        <a href="/" title="Home">
          <img class="logo-nav" src="https://unsplash.it/50x50" alt="My Logo">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for Navbar Logo and Links which may help you:

```css
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #222;
}

.navbar ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.navbar ul>li {
  display: block;
  float: right;
}

.navbar ul>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 26px 10px;
  color: #aaa;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar ul>li>a:hover{
  color:#fff
 }
.navbar .logo {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px
}

.navbar .logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
    <li class="logo"><img src="https://image.freepik.com/freie-ikonen/apple-logo_318-40184.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and very compatible way to solve vertical alignement is using table-cell display of the container element, in your case:

```
.col-4 {
    width:33.3%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:70px;
}
```

In order to remove the extra white space under baseline:

```
img {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

though not strictly necessary, a correct implementation of table-cell display should be completed with a display:table on the outer element; in your case:

```
.navbar{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #181827;
    display:table;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u7cogn51/